# Entity Framework: saving object to different entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm having a hard time with this problem... Basically i have 2 classes, Department and Location. Department has a `ICollection` of Location but Location doesn't have `DepartmentID` ( because a Location is not unique to a Department and the same location can be added to different Departments or different tables).

```
public class Department
{
    public Department()
    {
        this.LocationList = new HashSet<Location>();
        this.JobList = new HashSet<Job>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Location> LocationList { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Job> JobList { get; set; }

}


public class Location
    {

        public int id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Adress { get; set; }

    }
```

Whenever i try to create a Department and add a Location to it, Location gets a new attribute called `Department_ID` which (i think?) is the root of all my evils. So, if i add `Location1` with `ID = 1` and another `Location2` with `ID = 2`, then both Locations will have that `Department_ID = 1` (or another integer...). However, if i try to add `Location1` to a newly created Department, that Department will "steal" that Location from the other Department's `LocationList`, i'm guessing it's because the `Department_ID changes`. How can I make it ? so it doesn't take `Location1` away from the other Department? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked your database to see how its modeled? it look like you need to read about M to N relatioship, and get other table in order to have this working.

Comment: It's many to many Relationship. I think in Location class you must have a collection of Departement?

Comment: Check your design, as you did explain,  location must have a collection of department and not the departement has a collection of location.

Answer (score 1):

You need to let EF know that you have a many-to-many relation. Currently EF sees a one-to-many.

You can either add a `ICollection<Department>` to `Location` or configure it Fluently.

Documentation: [Configure Many-to-Many relationship:](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The relation between your `Location` and `Department` class is many to many. meaning a `Location` can be related to multiple `Department`s and a `Department` can be related to multiple `Location`s.
Define a new property for your `Location` class:

```
public Location()
{
    this.Departments = new HashSet<Department>();
}

public virtual ICollection<Department> Departments { get; set; }
```

Then in your context, use fluent mapping to define the relationship appropriately:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Department>()
            .HasMany<Location>(s => s.Locations)
            .WithMany(c => c.Departments)
            .Map(cs =>
                    {
                        cs.MapLeftKey("DepartmentId");
                        cs.MapRightKey("LocationId");
                        cs.ToTable("DepartmentsLocations");
                    });

}
```

This will create `DepartmentsLocations` table in your database with two columns: `DepartmentId` and `LocationId` which will handle many-to-many relation between Departments and Locations.